# how to compare date using where statement?

Tags: sql-server

i have a table called **dbo.reminder** in that i'm having a column name **rdate** i have declared that as

> NVARCHAR(50)

i want to sort the table using where condition with the present date how can i do that?

i have tried this query

```
SELECT rdetail,
       rid,
       rdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, rdate, 103), 103)
FROM   dbo.reminder  
where  rdate='23/01/2017'
```

but its not sorting please help me regarding this ?

Comment: Dates are dates, not text. Never ever store or treat dates as text. When you need to specify a date literal, use an unambiguous format, eg `20170123`

Comment: can you share a sample from rdate?

Comment: To put it another way, storing dates as text is a very serious, career&customer-limiting, contract-penalty-activating problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store date as `NVARCHAR`. Change your `rate` datatype to date and try this way

```
SELECT rdetail,rid,rdate 
FROM dbo.reminder  
where rdate = convert(date,'23/01/2017' ,103)
```

Convert the `varchar` date input to `date` and check with your `rate` column.

Better to pass imput in `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` format which is universal and does not require any conversion

If you cannot change the datatype then

```
SELECT rdetail,rid,rdate 
FROM dbo.reminder  
where convert(date,rdate,103) = convert(date,'23/01/2017' ,103)
```

Comment: getdate() function also can be used for present day instead of manually writing the day.

Comment: Thanks but its showing like this "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: @alisrn - Format is the real issue here I cannot use `Getdate()`

Comment: @Prdp an even better solution is to *avoid* that format entirely and use the unambiguous `20170123`. This is recognized as a date literal so there is no need to convert

Comment: @Prdp - The second one is working fine :-) can you please explain me how that actually works ?

Comment: @Suhas it's not really. Applying functions on a field means that the optimizer can't use any indexes with it so it has to scan the entire table. That means that your application will get *very* slow even with small amounts of data. Fix your schema.

Comment: @Suhas - You have stored dates as string in `dd/mm/yyyy` which cannot be converted to date without using style `103`. As Panagiotis said better send the input in `yyyymmdd` format or even `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @prdp but i'm using asp.net as front end where i'm taking input as date through a calendar so how can i store date in that `yyyy-mm-dd` fromat

Comment: Never ever ever store dates as anything else but dates. You might want to read this http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput